# ng-show not having any impact

Tags: angularjs, ng-show, angular1.6

I have this basic example of trying to use ng-show. I effectively only want to show a portion of the page if 'GB' is selected from the country drop down box. I have validated that the ctrl recieves 'GB' in it when i select GB from the dropdown box. However, the elements are not hidden on the page initially and selecting things from the select box has no impact. I'd appreciate any help.

```
<ng-form name="directorsForm" cc-pitch-form="5" ng-controller="work.myCtrl as ctrl">
    <div class="row cc-form__group">
        <div class="columns large-3">
            <label>Country</label>
        </div>
        <div class="columns large-3 left">
            <select ng-options="country.code as country.name for country in ctrl.countryList" ng-model="ctrl.selectedCountry" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div ng-show="ctrl.selectedCountry =='GB'">
        <div class="columns large-3">
            <label>Enter address</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-form>
```

Comment: show your controller

Comment: Your ng-show looks fine, the bug is probably in your controller or ng-options

Comment: my controller doesn't have any logic relating to this in it.

Comment: @MattBoyle Certainly it has

Comment: Does it need to? As i am certain it does not.

Comment: Can you show us the final html generated by the select ?

Comment: if I inspect it in chrome, it has around 100 options,here are the first 5
<option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
<option label="Afghanistan" value="string:AF">Afghanistan</option>
<option label="Åland Islands" value="string:AX">Åland Islands</option>
<option label="Albania" value="string:AL">Albania</option>
<option label="Algeria" value="string:DZ">Algeria</option>

Comment: I also have Angularjs devtools and if I inspect the controller after selecting an option, I can see selectedCountry: "GB" is in the controller.

Comment: how have your declared the controller?

Comment: Looks like angular cannot work with an incorrect `select` that closes itself. See [this working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fzvtyay3/1/). You have to change `<select .. />` to `<select ..></select>`

Comment: this worked. Thanks so much, I never would have spotted that. I have been writing too much react it seems :)

Answer (score 0):

replace this line

```
<select ng-options="country.code as country.name for country in ctrl.countryList" ng-model="ctrl.selectedCountry" />
```

like this

```
<select ng-options="country.code as country.name for country in ctrl.countryList" ng-model="ctrl.selectedCountry" ></select>
```

self closing in select is not working in angular i hope it helps!!